# Corona + Android 2.2 + HTC Gratia problem

Tags: android, coronasdk

I've developed an Android application with Corona SDK, I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 myself which I've used to try my application with.

But today I heard that a friend that has a HTC Gratia A6380 recieved an error when he was trying to download the application from Android Market. 
It said "This application is not comaptible with Tele2 HTC HTC Gratia A6380."

I can't understand why.

With Android SDK I ran this command:
**./aapt dump badging AppName.apk**

```
package: name='com.mypackage.app' versionCode='10' versionName='1.0'
sdkVersion:'8'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE'
uses-gl-es:'0x10001'
application-label:'AppName'
application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
application: label='AppName' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png'
launchable-activity: name='com.ansca.corona.CoronaActivity'  label='AppName' icon=''
uses-library:'com.google.android.maps'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.landscape'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
main
other-activities
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '120' '160' '240'
native-code: '' 'armeabi-v7a'
```

The application uses the "shake"-function, but I guess HTC Gratia has that function, and apparently it's not a requirement either.

Does anyone has a clue why it's not compatible with HTC Gratia? Or at least can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Corona apps built after Corona daily build 328 have two requirements that must be met for the code to run on any given phone, first that they have Android 2.2 or newer, and secondly that the CPU in the phone uses the ARMv7 instruction set. You can see in the dump that it requires

```
"native-code: '' 'armeabi-v7a'".
```

Using pdadb.net I found that the htc gratia uses the qualcomm msm7227 chip, which is an ARMv6 instruction set chip and therefore not supported. If this is the same phone that your friend has then he won't be able to use your application unless you download corona daily build 327 or earlier and recompile your code.

Resources:

I can't post more than two links, but if you google '"Building for Devices Android" Corona' then you should find the anscamobile post I am talking about
[PDADB.NET entry for HTC Gratia](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=specs&id=2652&c=htc_gratia_htc_liberty)
[PDADB.NET entry for the Qualcomm msm7227 chip](http://pdadb.net/index.php?m=cpu&id=a7227&c=qualcomm_msm7227)